# Quickest way to add a field to each document in a large couchDB using python

Tags: python, random, couchdb, couchdb-python

I have a couchDB with over 1 million entries spread over a few databases. I need to draw random samples from such that I have a record of the members of each sample. To that end, and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779605/how-do-i-load-a-random-document-from-couchdb-efficiently-and-fairly) question **I want to add a field with a random number to every document in my couchDB.**

**Code to add a random number**

```
def add_random_fields():
    from numpy.random import rand
    server = couchdb.Server()
    databases = [database for database in server if not database.startswith('_')]
    for database in databases:
        print database
        for document in server[database]:
            if 'results' in server[database][document].keys():
                for tweet in server[database][document]['results']:
                    if 'rand_num' not in tweet.keys():
                        tweet['rand_num'] = rand()
                        server[database].save(tweet)
```

This fails because I do not have enough RAM to hold a copy of all my CouchDB databases.

**First attempt- load databases in chunks**

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) question.

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

# ..Just showing relevant part of add_random_fields()

   #..
        chunk_size=100
        for tweet in grouper(server[database][document]['results'],chunk_size):
```

If I were iterating over a large list in python, I would write a generator expression. How can I do that in couchdb-python? Or, is there a better way?

Comment: Would just writing a couch view to return documents with random number be viable? Then just access that view - ie, if you wanted a 1 in 10 sample, then return a number between 1 and 10, with a document idea, which'll automatically be sorted, and then use itertools.groupby in Python to retrieve full document where needed ?

Comment: @JonClements I want to be able to recreate the same random sample. I thought associating a random number with each document in the database was the most direct way to do that. How would I recreate a specific sample, using your approach?

Answer (score -1):

**Use a generator to avoid loading large lists into memory**

From [Marcus Brinkmann](http://blog.marcus-brinkmann.de/2011/09/17/a-better-iterator-for-python-couchdb/) I found code to make a generator over all documents in a couchDB database. Let that generator be called `couchdb_pager`.

The original function becomes the following.

```
def add_random_fields():
    from numpy.random import rand
    server = couchdb.Server()
    databases = [database for database in server if not database.startswith('_')]
    for database in databases:
        for document in couchdb_pager(server[database]):
            if 'results' in server[database][document]:
                for tweet in server[database][document]['results']:
                    if tweet and 'rand_num' not in tweet:
                        print document
                        tweet['rand_num'] = rand()
                        server[database].save(tweet)
```